# What does 'default-initialization in copy-initialization context' mean in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, overloading, c++17

For example I guess I understand what list-initialization in context of direct-initialization (vs copy-) mean - `int x{}` vs `int x = {}` basically.

But on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Initialization_by_constructor) I found this:

> When an object of class type is copy-initialized from an object of the same or derived class type, or default-initialized in a copy-initialization context, the candidate functions are all converting constructors of the class being initialized. The argument list is the expression of the initializer.

I guess I understand why candidates are converting constructors for the first case, but not for the second. I mean, I can't write something like `MyClass x = MyClass`, and `= MyClass()` would be a value-initialization, and `= MyClass(args...)` would be a direct-initilization.

And even if such a construct existed, I don't see why a temporary `MyClass` object 'construction' should include specifically all converting constructors.

(And `x` is not something that's talked about here as I see, because it's definitely copy-constructed, not default-constructed.)

So I guess I'm confused with the terms here.

Comment: The [wording in the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.ctor-1.sentence-2) is pretty similar, and I too don't know what default-initialization in a copy-initialization context might mean. +1.

Comment: I wonder if it is saying that `Myclass Foo = Myclass(10, "foo"});` just becomes `Myclass foo(10, "foo");`

Comment: _"could include only the converting constructors (and not the default one)_". Why not the default one? Any nonexplicit constructor (including default) is a converting constructor. Moreover, you can have a default constructor such as `MyClass::MyClass(int i = 0);`.

Comment: @DanielLangr I didn't actually know that (that all the non-explicit ones are converting), thanks; removed the detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wording is added in the paper [P0398R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0398r0.html), which is intented to describe the following case:

```
Z c = {};
```

for non-aggregate `Z`.

Comment: Hm, but isn't `c` value-initialized here? even for the non-aggregate case

Comment: How is that direct- or default-initialization though? Isn't it value-initialization?

Comment: @Barry value-init goes through default-init.

Comment: And all similar cases of copy-list-initialization from `{}`, basically.

Comment: So to me it seems more like a value-initialization in copy-initialization context than the default- one, but whatever, it doesn't matter too much

Comment: I'm not getting the point where the conversion constructor comes into play here.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia That is to say, if the default constructor of `Z` is explicit (thus not a converting constructor), it is not a candidate, thus the initialization is ill-formed.

Comment: @xskxzr that means, that the default constructor is also considered a conversion.... then my answer below is not wrong either.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia Your answer is of course correct... but how is it related to the question?

Answer (score -3):

This means, when you initialize an object, it is not default constructed and then copied using assignment operator, but always immediately constructed from the parameters given in the initialization. Therefore it uses only the conversions, when you use the assignment notation.

Example: 
Given the class:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass();
    MyClass(int);
};
```

The following statement are only calling the MyClass::MyClass(int) and no default constructor.

```
MyClass obj = 10;
MyClass obj{10};
MyClass obj = {10};
```

Comment: Those are *not* identical.

Comment: @Barry plz explain

Comment: e.g. `struct X { explicit X(std::initializer_list<int> ); X(int ); };` `X obj = 10;` calls the 2nd constructor, `X obj{10};` calls the 1st constructor, and `X obj = {10};` is ill-formed.

Comment: @DanielLangr Well, then it is not a conversion constructor.

Comment: @Berry Yes... right ... Edited post to mention initalizer_list<int> is not present.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia (a) that's not how you spell my name (b) You really cannot describe things as "identical" that have different resolution paths - I can always find you cases where behavior differs. New example, `struct Y { int i; };`, `Y obj{10}` is okay and `Y obj = 10;` is ill-formed.

Comment: @Barry (sorry for wrong spelling) .. The comment with concerning 'not converting constructor was addressed at Daniel Langr 's comment. 
What you think about the answer as it is now?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: That is how I understand the paragraph in the standard that you referenced above. Something like... Even if MyClass obj = {10} looks like a default construction plus assignment, it is actually only a converting construction. (given the constraints already discussed)

Comment: Default initialization does not mean initialization by default constructor.